# How do you modify the title font options for a single slide in Beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm writing a presentation in Beamer, the default options for the font title are the following

```
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\Large,
                            series=\bfseries,
                            parent=structure}
```

I want to override those option just for a couple of slides, but I didn't find any answer.
For example, I'd like to lower the size and eliminate the bold

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my issue by placing

```
\begin{frame}{\normalsize{FRAMETITLE}}
  
\end{frame}
```

in the frame I needed to modify. I know it was stupid, just to say I solved

Comment: Font size commands are switches and don't take an argument. Instead of `\normalsize{...}` it should be `{\normalsize ...}`

Comment: ... also if you are using an all caps title: wouldn't it make more sense to use smallcaps and keep the default size?

Comment: I put the caps lock just to highlight it was the title. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict any changes you make to only a couple of frames if you make them within a group `{...}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\Large, series=\bfseries, parent=structure}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide B}
Content for slide B
\end{frame}  

{   
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Tiny, series=\normalfont}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide B}
Content for slide B
\end{frame}  
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide B}
Content for slide B
\end{frame}  
  
\end{document}
```